# AD Sites and Services - Adding Subnets

Tags: active-directory

We have various physical sites with servers, workstation, printers, switches, and routers.  Is there a reason to add subnets that do not contain Windows devices? For example printers or switches? We have separate subnets for these devices.

Thank You!

Comment: IMO, it's always bet practice to add all of your sites and subnets to ADS&S.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I guess its sort of like having a belt and suspenders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a *technical* reason.  Devices that are not joined to Active Directory and don't use AD for authentication aren't going to leverage AD Sites and Subnets.

One reason for doing it anyway would be thoroughness. Having all your subnets accounted for in AD, even if the subnet has no AD clients in it, is one way of having your environment being self-documenting.

Comment: Couldn't ADSS be used to define a subnet of devices that would provide location based dns responses from a windows DNS server? You might have the same printer in 3 offices and instead of setting up 3 different devices on a laptop you just give it a location based name to reply with the IP that is used in that particular location's printer subnet.

Comment: @ChrisB That is not a function of AD Sites and Services, but rather a function of DNS server subnet mask ordering, which will work regardless of what subnet objects are set up in AD.